# Get Only rows from primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1:

```
ID  Year    MatchNumber
0   0       0
1   2017    1
2   2017    2
3   2017    3
4   2017    4
5   2016    1
6   2016    2
7   2016    3
8   2016    4
9   2015    1
10  2015    2
11  2015    3
12  2015    4
13  2017    5
```

Table 2:

```
Year        MatchNumber
2017        1
2017        2
2017        3
2017        4
2016        1
2016        2
2016        3
2016        4
2015        1
2015        2
2015        3
2015        4
```

Expected output: based on case condition
Case 1:

If Id is 0 then 0;

Case 2 if `Id <> 0` and yeat and matchnumber match then 1

Else 2

```
ID     Year     MatchNumber   conditionMatched
0      0        0             0
1      2017     1             1
2      2017     2             1
3      2017     3             1
4      2017     4             1
5      2016     1             1
6      2016     2             1
7      2016     3             1
8      2016     4             1
9      2015     1             1
10     2015     2             1
11     2015     3             1
12     2015     4             1
13     2017     5             2
```

I have one more table Category to include in join.
Categoryid CategoryName
0                 X
1                 Y
2                 Z
Instead marking based on hard code 0,1,2; I need to join category table mark its value..

Comment: What is your question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have different cases?
So use CASE statement :)

```
SELECT  ID, 
        T1.[Year], 
        T1.MatchNumber, 
        CASE WHEN ID=0 THEN 0 
            WHEN T2.[year] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
            WHEN T2.[year] IS NULL THEN 2 
                END AS conditionMatched
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 
    ON T1.[year]=T2.[year] AND T1.MatchNumber=T2.MatchNumber
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way ([IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) could be used since SQL Server 2012 and [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) since SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.[Year],
        t.MatchNumber,
        IIF(t.ID>0,2,0)-COALESCE(p.MatchNumber-t.MatchNumber+1,0)
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table2 p
    ON t.[year] = p.[year] 
        AND t.MatchNumber = p.MatchNumber
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [Value] = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.[Year] = t1.[Year] AND t2.[MatchNumber] = t1.[MatchNumber])
        THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END
```

Case is nice to use here, but the left join may cause multiple rows to be returned when an entry is found more than once in the second table. May be better to use the EXISTS construction mentioned above